# Bullet script for shooting multiple targets

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to find a way for the Enemy to shoot at multiple players or Objects and I don't know where to start.
I'm currently using Unity 2017

Here's the bullet script

Much Appreciated

```
using UnityEngine;

using System.Collections;

public class MultiBulletScript:

  MonoBehaviour {
    GameObject[] target;
    public float speed;
    Rigidbody2D bulletRB;
    GameObject destroyObject;
    Vector3 respawn = new Vector3(-36, 0, 0);
    public GameObject blood;

    // Use this for initialization  void Start ()   {
    bulletRB = GetComponent < Rigidbody2D > ();
    target = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");
    Vector2 moveDir = (target.transform.position - transform.position).normalized * speed;
    bulletRB.velocity = new Vector2(moveDir.x, moveDir.y);
    Destroy(this.gameObject, 2);
  }

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
  if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
    Instantiate(blood, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    other.gameObject.transform.position = respawn;
  }

  if (other.CompareTag("Bullet")) {
    Destroy(other.gameObject);
    Destroy(gameObject);
  }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `List` for objects you want to shoot at. Something like this:

```
public List<Transform> targets = new List<Transform>();
```

After this, you need to calculate the direction for all of them. Such as this (where `gunPosition` is where you want to spawn the bullet and `shootRotation` is the rotation of your bullet when you shoot it):

```
public void Start()
{
   foreach(Transform target in targets)
   {
       Vector3 shootDirection = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;
       GameObject newBullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, gunPosition, shootRotation)
       newBullet.GetComponent<RigidBody>().velocity = shootDirection * shootSpeed;
   }    
}
```

However, this goes into your enemy controller script. Bullets should only have a small amount of code. They only need to detect the TriggerEnter.

But be aware! Too much `OnTriggerEnter` calculation in the scene can have an impact on your performance (dropping fps).

So I would create one script on each player with an `OnTriggerEnter` so they detect if a bullet hits them. They can destroy the bullet as well.

```
public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
   if(other.tag == "Bullet")
   {
       //Do blood effect
       //Damage player
       Destroy(other.transform.root.gameObject);
   }
}
```

It is better, because there always be less player then bullet, so your game is more optimized. Hope I could help!

Comment: I'll look into it 

Comment: Good luck with that! Let me know if you need more help!

Comment: I edited the first code part, you should calculate the direction and make it normalized (as you did originally). I forgot to put the .normalized at the end of the calculation.

Comment: Is it possible to put in its own bullet script without reference to the Enemy script because I didn't want to confuse myself with other scripts.